# polishing LXDE by fixing the scroll bars

Tags: lxde

I like LXDE, but how can I get full, always showing, scroll bars on my windows, and
not the "pop-up scroll bars which cause me time and trouble?

Comment: Could you please clarify your question in words or by providing an image? What exactly are you using? What do you mean by "I like LXDE"? Do mention the actual OS you are using and if you modified it, how. If you simply were using pure Lubuntu instead of something else (which you have not named), the question of "pop-up scroll bars" wouldn't arise.

Comment: Anyone who searched for this question exactly what the OP is asking here. Unity hides scrollbars to make windows look "prettier". No matter what other DE is installed (eg. LXDE), the scrollbars remain hidden until you hover around searching for them (absolutely an anti-pattern in UI design). SO is not intended as a free source of text for paid writers, who should not expect free editing too.

Answer (score 4):

Try this guide: http://ubuntuguide.net/disable-turn-off-overlay-scrollbars-in-ubuntu-12-10

Short version:
 * Open dconf-editor
 * Navigate to key "com -> canonical -> desktop -> interface"
 * change the value of "scrollbar-mode" to "normal"
 * Log out and back in

Comment: Please edit your answer to provide one more step, that of installing whatever provides "dconf-editor" because I'm not sure that "dconf-editor" is present by default.

Comment: This still allows the slider in the scroll bar to auto resize, and is perhaps more annoying than the overlay.

Comment: Lubuntu 16.04 doesn't seem to have any of these options, there's no "desktop" item under com->canonical

Answer (score 2):

install lubuntu-desktop, and login to lubuntu at the login screen.  then run "Customize look and feel" select clearlooks-olive or similar theme that has classic scrollbars.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Much more comprehensive than fiddling with dconf.

Comment: It seems like as of Lubuntu 16.04 only Lubuntu-Default and Lubuntu-dark-panel have permanent scrollbars (with no buttons, unfortunately), Clearlooks has the popup bars. I ended up looking for this option because annoyingly Redmond's scrollbars would pop up and obscure text on the bottom of the screen...